# Pip Post-install Script Interactive Input?

Tags: python, pip, post-install

I'm very new to python packaging, and trying to make a pip compatible setup and post-install script for my package for colleagues.  The goal of the post-install script is to create a configuration file that will be customized to the end-user and their system, and while I guess I could just have them run a secondary setup script post installation, it seems to make more sense to me to just have the setup.py script and associated post-install handle things.

The issue is that while using either easy-install or un-tarballing the package and running `python setup.py install` work fine, pip will not.  I think it may be that pip is inhibiting interaction with stdout and stdin based on this [discussion from 2015](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2732), but I'm not sure if that's the case or I'm just not doing it correctly.  Even if I use `-vvv` with `pip install` I still don't get output or interactivity from my post-install.py script.

Does anyone know a good workaround to get a post installation script to run interactively with pip?  The post install script is a bit long, so I won't post it here, but here is my setup.py script in case I need to handle it from here:

```
import sys, os
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.install import install as _install
from subprocess import call

import my_package

def _post_install(dir):
    call([sys.executable, 'postinstall.py'])


class install(_install):
    def run(self):
        _install.do_egg_install(self)
        self.execute(_post_install, (self.install_lib,), msg="Running post install task")

def readme():
    with open('README.rst') as fh:
        return fh.read()

config = {
    'name'                   : 'my_package',
    'description'            : ('My Package'),
    'long_description'       : readme(),
    'version'                : my_package.__version__,
    'author'                 : 'My Name',
    'author_email'           : 'my.email@email.com',
    'download_url'           : 'https://download.link.com',
    'test_suite'             : 'nose.collector',
    'tests_require'          : ['nose'],
    'packages'               : ['my_package'],
    'install_requires'       : ['requests'],
    'scripts'                : ['bin/script1.py',
                                'bin/script2.py',
                               ],
    'include_package_data'   : True,
    'zip_safe'               : False,
    'license'                : 'MIT',
    'cmdclass'               : {'install' : install}
}

setup(**config)
```